# Какими способами можно посчитать выражение в строке?

Tags: c#, строки

Задана строка символов, состоящая из букв, цифр, точек, символов «+» и «-». Заменить все выражения на их решение.

Ввод:

> "abc 57 + 7 9 - 5 cda"

Вывод:

> "abc 64 4 cda"

Мой код:

```
string text = "abc 57 + 7 9 - 5 cda";
string firstOperand = "";
string secondOperand = "";
int startInd = 0;
int j = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < text.Length; i++)
{
    firstOperand = "";
    secondOperand = "";
    startInd = 0;
    j = 0;
    if (text[i] == '+' || text[i] == '-')
    {
        text = text.Remove(i - 1, 1);
        text = text.Remove(i, 1);
        j = i-2;
        while (j > 0 && Char.IsDigit(text[j]))
        {
            firstOperand += text[j];
            j--;
        }
        startInd = j;
        firstOperand = String.Join("", firstOperand.Reverse().ToArray());
        j = i;
        while (j < text.Length && Char.IsDigit(text[j]))
        {
            secondOperand += text[j];
            j++;
        }
        switch (text[i - 1])
        {
            case '+':
                text = text.Remove(startInd, j - startInd);
                text = text.Insert(startInd, $" {Convert.ToInt32(firstOperand) + Convert.ToInt32(secondOperand)}");
                break;
            case '-':
                text = text.Remove(startInd, j - startInd);
                text = text.Insert(startInd, $" {Convert.ToInt32(firstOperand) - Convert.ToInt32(secondOperand)}");
                break;
        }
    }
}
Console.WriteLine(text);
```

Comment: а в чем вопрос?

Comment: @tym32167 Можно ли это сделать какими-либо методами, с помощью linq и т.д.

Comment: С помощью Linq можно сделать всё, но это не значит, что всё надо делать с помощью Linq